# What happens to a primitive float value when sent through HTTP?

Tags: floating-point

I have an API that looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/floattest")
@ResponseBody
public ApiResult getFloatTest() {
    ApiResult result = new ApiResult();
    ApiObject test = new ApiObject(81684436f, 74258578f, 7425858f);
    result.setData(test);
    return result;
}

public class BalanceDetail {
    private float a;
    private float b;
    private float c;
}
```

API call returns:

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": 81684432,
        "b": 74258576,
        "c": 7425858
    }
}
```

I've skimmed through a floating-point document, but have additional questions.

1. Does the browser receives `8.1684432E7`? or `81684432?`
2. What happens to `8.1684432E7` before and after HTTP protocol?

Comment: Note that `8.1684432e7` and `81684432` are just different **textual** representations of the **exact same** binary number.